# Users able to circumvent sharing for custom object on visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, sharing, apex-sharing

We have an object which has private sharing settings. There are no sharing rules on the custom object. But if the user(not owner of the record) knows the Id and paste it in the browser ..he is able to see the record. My guess it is because the record is the visualforce page. Why would a vf page not behaving like a standard record page where it is shows the record is not accessbile?

Comment: Does the controller of the VF page use the 'with sharing' keywords in the class declaration?

Comment: there is no sharing keyword in the controller

Comment: add that to the declaration.  Public with sharing Class yourClassName{

Answer (score 3):

You should use the 'with sharing' keywords in your VF page controller class declaration.  This enforces sharing rules as Apex, by default operates in system mode.

**From the documentation**

> 'You have to explicitly set this keyword for the class because Apex
>   code runs in system context. In system context, Apex code has access
>   to all objects and fields— object permissions, field-level security,
>   sharing rules aren’t applied for the current user.'

Something like this

```
public with sharing class yourClassName{
    //your class
}
```

**See the documentation here**

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm

Comment: User is not able to see the record unless he knows Id of the record.

Comment: I don't understand.  Is that a statement or a question?

Comment: Additional info on this answer: If the code is a StandardController extension class it will inherit the 'with sharing' behavior which exists by default on the StandardController when it is not explicitly specified in the extension class declaration. It is best practice to explicitly specify the 'with sharing' keywords. In specific use cases, helper classes which specify 'without sharing' can be leveraged to provide access to data which the current user does not otherwise have access to - but these cases are few.

Comment: Right now user is not able to see the record (I have not added any sharing keyword in the controller)..He only sees the record if he knows the ID

Comment: I guess I dont understand what you mean by 'if he knows the ID'.  Is he adding the Id to the URL to access the VF page?  I dont understand what you are saying

Comment: If he adds the Id to the URL

Comment: ok, so have you tried what I suggested, adding the with sharing to the class declaration?